# What exactly does the AcceptPathInfo directive do?

Tags: apache, apache-config

The core documentation for v. 2.4 of Apache tells me that the AcceptPathInfo directive

> "controls whether requests that contain trailing pathname information that follows an actual filename (or non-existent file in an existing directory) will be accepted or rejected."

I would take that to mean that a request containing trailing pathname information would be rejected with an Apache error unless AcceptPathInfo was turned on.  What I'm finding is that requests with trailing pathname information do not receive an Apache error whether or not AcceptPathInfo is turned on.  In fact, it seems that the status of AcceptPathInfo has no affect on the way that Apache handles requests that contain trailing path information.  What am I missing?  I'm running httpd v. 2.4.6.  Thanks for any input.

... doug

Comment: Perhaps the pathinfo just isn't passed on to the resource being called? Not sure...

Comment: I figured it out.  Here's what I'm missing. AcceptPathInfo has 3 possible states rather than just 2 (On, Off, and Default). All states work as one would expect.  I got confused by thinking that omitting a declaration would correspond to the "Off" state when, in fact, it corresponds to the "Default State".  It's all good.  Thanks.

Comment: Cool. That might be a worthy self-answer!